# groupby apply Pandas not yielding desired output

Tags: python, pandas

Below is a small sample of my dataframe : I am trying a groupby.apply which is not giving me the desired result.

```
 In [204]: df1
Out[204]:
        Location_ID Terminal                Time
0        10000001405702   *WhF   2016-07-01 13:56:00
1        10000001405702   @W1n   2016-07-01 09:14:39
2        10000001405702   *Wu3   2016-07-01 11:54:52
3        10000001405702   @WJo   2016-07-01 11:30:57
4        10000001405702   @WCg   2016-07-01 11:06:24
5        10000001405702   *WL2   2016-07-01 10:04:20
6        10000001201132   A24O   2016-07-01 14:28:39
7        10000000564967   2JT1   2016-07-01 03:46:31
8        10000000615068   A125   2016-07-01 21:58:33
9        10000000552415   5MTH   2016-07-01 05:51:39
10       10000001405702   *WqW   2016-07-01 00:09:06
11       10000000250413   FF41   2016-07-01 02:59:43
12       10000001125037   WQ2I   2016-06-30 14:03:57
13       10000000174015   H5NM   2016-06-30 05:56:09
14       10000001856529   AR7K   2016-06-30 18:53:05
```

By doing the below groupby.apply , I am losing the Location_ID and Terminal information , but I need that .

```
In [206]: df1.groupby(['Location_ID','Terminal'])['Time'].apply(lambda x : x.diff()<=dt.timedelta(seconds=60))
Out[206]:
0          False
1          False
2          False
3          False
4          False
5          False
6          False
7          False
8          False
9          False
10         False
11         False
12         False
13         False
14         False
15         False
16         False
17         False
```

I need an output of below format such that The boolean info can be known for Location_IDs and Terminal.

```
In [211]: df3
Out[211]:
                                            Time
Location_ID        Terminal
10000000000081     3ZR1                    False
                   CDE1                    True
                   CDE4                     False
                   GIG2                     True
                   L43L                     False
                   L43W                     False
                   W9YE                     True
                   YIW1                     False
                   YIW4                     True
                   ZYI7                     True
                   ZYJN                     False
10000000000086     A1E6                     False
                   A4DG                      True
```

Still trying to find my grip in pandas. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to do? It's not obvious from your expected output...

Comment: This is transaction data. At a location_ID how many terminals have transactions happening in less then or equal to 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of your operation is a pandas Series. If you want it to be a column in a Dataframe you need to assign it to one.

Make `df3` as a copy of `df1` and change your call to:

```
df3['Time'] = df1.groupby(['Location_ID','Terminal'])['Time'].apply(lambda x : x.diff()<=dt.timedelta(seconds=60))
```

Also, you apparently want 'Location_ID' and 'Terminal' as indexes of the Dataframe.

Comment: do I need to re index my df3 which is df1.copy()? Because , if I reindex then I am getting Nans instead of "bool" values.

Comment: You're having trouble distinguishing references and copies, I think. Try `df3.groupby` instead of `df1.groupby` in the code I posted, and then reset the index to the columns you want